# Please help me for nginx custom log format issue with goacccess

Tags: nginx, log-analysis, goaccess

**Please find my log output for nginx (access.log)**

> 182.69.143.120 - - [31/Mar/2016:03:10:51 +0530] "GET /api/check_delivery.php?authkey=9450AW2qTKYe453be757c&requestid=36626f6a3530323439383831 HTTP/1.1" control.msg91.com 404 39 "-" "-" "-" "control.msg91.com" "-" to: 10.0.0.62:8080: upstream_response_time 0.003 request_time 0.003

**My nginx custom log format :**

> $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $host'
> '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
> '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" "$server_name"';

**and  which i am using in goaccess conf file:**

> time-format %H:%M:%S
>
> date-format %d/%b/%Y
>
> log_format %^[%d:%^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u" "%^ %h"

**and after running this I am getting below error:**

> GoAccess - version 0.9.8 - Mar 31 2016 14:11:22
> Config file: /usr/local/etc/goaccess.conf
>
> Fatal error has occurred
> Error occured at: src/goaccess.c - main - 1017
> Nothing valid to process. Verify your date/time/log format.

Please help me out...
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

try with the following log format :

```
log-format %h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s %b "%R" "%u"
```